# Relationship between voltage to a speaker and the resulting sound pressure generated

Tags: acoustics, voltage

So a question, suppose V, voltage, is a function of time V(t). Lets suppose you are playing a song on a speaker, lets assume you know the songs tone for a channel 1 and channel 2 for all 0

I'm curious, how would you relate V(t) to the sound pressure generated by playing the song? My intuition says that, if you increase the voltage fed to the speaker, the louder to sound, so the sound pressure must be greater.

So if $P_{speaker}$ is the acoustic pressure for a specific voltage, I'm interesting in finding a simple relationship for $P_{speaker}(V(t))$. I.e for a fixed song, and voltage at a time unit t, what sound pressure would be generated?